# A number of dropdown boxes - only wish to get data from one. How?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, dom-events

I have a form with a varying number of dropdown boxes rendered with HTML. I wish to pass to the user a value from one of these dropdown boxes - just one value. How can I do this? It's such a simple thing but I have spent hours on it.

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="nextStep.cshtml">
   <select name="1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>

   <select name="2">
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>

   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

And in nextStep.cshtml I have :

`var number = Request.form[//what can I do here?];`

The dropdowns names are populated in a loop. The functionality I wish to have is for the user to select a value from one dropdown, and all others to be disabled. I then want to be able to extract just this piece of data in nextStep.cshtml.

How can I do this?

Error is in this code :

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#form select').change(function(){
      var thisDd = $(this);
      $('#myValueField').val(thisDd.val());
      $('#form select').each(function(i, e){
          if(thisDd.val() == ""){
            $(e).attr('enabled', 'enabled');
          } else{ 
          if(e==thisDd[0]) return; // not disable myself
          $(e).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // disable other
        }
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So you have a bunch of dropdowns effectively operating as a single one?  Why not combine them?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan Logically that wouldn't make sense in my context - the data needs to be separated out and separate dropdowns is the best way to do this.

Comment: Not to be too nosy, but why?  Is it because there are too many options?  If you're just looking to help your user find it?  If so, then the <optgroup> tag might be what you're looking for.  If there are too many options, perhaps a select isn't the right choice anyway.  More information on your use case will help us find a more workable answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I had thought optgroup as well, however the data needs to be split up more than this. A lot of values are being displayed to the user, it makes more sense for me to utilize available screen space so the user can quickly choose the field he wishes :). The data is a central point in an algorithm, and all thats needed is one input from the user. Separate drop downs make sense here, though I agree it would usually be silly! :)

Comment: Is this the only thing being collected on the page?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan Yes, it is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do this (not tested):

```
<hidden name="myValueField" id="myValueField">

// Submit the form after selection
$(function(){
   $('#form select').change(function(){
      $('#myValueField').val($(this).val());
      $('#form').submit();
   });
});

// or disable other dropdowns after selection
$(function(){
   $('#form select').change(function(){
      var thisDd = $(this);
      $('#myValueField').val(thisDd.val());
      $('#form select').each(function(i, e){
          if(e==thisDd[0]) return; // not disable myself
          $(e).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // disable other
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response. When I try to run your code, I call  string test = Request.Form["myValueField"]; and it returns null. I have added the hidden field to my form, and the function to head but it still does not appear to work. Any ideas?

Comment: silly me, I had the HTML wrong! Should have had    <input type="hidden" name="myValueField" id="myValueField">! Any ideas how I can, on user selection of a value, disable all other boxes?

Comment: I updated my answer - still no guarantee because typed without testing :)

Comment: Yep, works, just had to proof it [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/97aWf/) :)

Comment: that's a really helpful solution! Thanks very much! :) I've updated my code above to show a slight change I was trying to make to it, I wanted to make it so if the user selects a value in the dropdown box that has the empty string value, the dropboxes would all be enabled again, however my code isn't working. Can you see anything wrong with it ?

Comment: There is no `enabled` attribute, you have to write `$(e).removeAttr('disabled');` instead of `$(e).attr('enabled', 'enabled');`.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this. One way would be to just set a hidden input using Javascript with the value you want to process on the server.